# Slicing part of a JSON in a dataframe column

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing JSON as -

```
Q1
[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}]
[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}]
[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}, {'id': '1-5', 'content': 'PQR'}]
```

How can I make this column look like this -

```
Q1
ABC, XYZ
ABC
ABC, XYZ, PQR
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that sets up the dataframe just like yours, then converts and extracts the contents:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Q1'], index=range(3))
df['Q1'][0]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}]  
df['Q1'][1]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}]
df['Q1'][2]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}, {'id': '1-5', 'content': 'PQR'}]


a = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//len(df)).agg(list)['Q1'][0]

def getcontent(x): 
   clist = [] 
   for item in x[0]: 
      if item != None: 
         clist.append(item['content']) 
   return clist 

temp = pd.DataFrame(a)
temp.T.groupby(np.arange(len(temp.T))//len(temp.T)).agg(list).apply(getcontent) 
df['Q1'] = temp.T.groupby(np.arange(len(temp.T))//len(temp.T)).agg(list).apply(getcontent)
```

output:

```
                Q1
0       [ABC, XYZ]
1            [ABC]
2  [ABC, XYZ, PQR]
```

Comment: this gives me an error - `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'` on `a = df.groupby ...`

Comment: @harry04 i removed the to_numpy and referenced it directly, that might work. not sure why the numpy isn't working, it works here, but this solution works as well

Comment: `TypeError: ('string indices must be integers', 'occurred at index 0')` occuring on `temp.T.groupby(...`

Comment: if you want to look at it more, give me your output for  pd.__version__   and i will install it and test my code against your version of pandas. i don't mind. i'm running 0.25.3

Comment: mine is `0.23.4`. Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: i got my code to work perfectly on 0.23.4. Maybe it's a numpy issue, i'm on version '1.16.2'  np.__version__

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Q1'], index=range(3))
df['Q1'][0]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}]  
df['Q1'][1]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}]
df['Q1'][2]=[{'id':'1-1', 'content': 'ABC'}, {'id':'1-3', 'content': 'XYZ'}, {'id': '1-5', 'content': 'PQR'}]


_dd = [{i:l['content']} for i,e in enumerate(df['Q1']) for l in e]
d ={}
for l in _dd:
    for v in l:
        if d.get(v):
            d[v] = '{},{}'.format(d[v], l[v]) 
        else:
            d[v] = l[v]

pd.DataFrame([d[k] for k in d], columns=['Q1'])
```

This will return

```
    Q1
0   ABC,XYZ
1   ABC
2   ABC,XYZ,PQR
```

Comment: `df` is not referenced anywhere?!